# Reduce waiting time for data from server

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, flask

My app calls my Python server to get some information. The information takes time to process before sending the data back to my app. Hence, the user waits for approximately 12 seconds, in order to get the data from the server.

Is there any way that the app could receive the data in multiple batches (once some data has been processed, it gets sent to the app, and then when more data gets processed, more data gets sent to the app)?

**I only know how to receive one batch of data per server call using NSURLConnection/AFJSONRequestOperation, is there any way to receive multiple batches of data per server call with iOS?**

Comment: If you need me to clarify anything regarding the question, please let me know.

Comment: Is using WebSockets an option in your infrastructure?

Comment: @HansThen I am on Heroku, with a Python/Flask app at the moment. From what I know, WebSockets don't work with Heroku.

Comment: There was a discussion here to do something similar: http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2011/12/5/long-polling-with-flask-on-heroku/#4881825ec173f07328048c69c8edc861

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to request each chunk independently.

1. Add the following meta data to each response (I assumed you are using JSON)

   ```
   {
       pagination: {
           page: 1,
           pages: 5,
           next_url: 'http://domain.com/database/search?&query=query&page=2'
       },
       data: 'your data'
   }
   ```
2. Once first chunk is received on the client side, request the next one using `next_url`